# Problem with \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

Tags: hyphenation

I wanted to prevent hypernation in my document so I used 
"\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}". The problem I am having is that my document margins are being compromised with it. 
I am using: \documentclass[12pt]{gatech-thesis}

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: since hyphenation is only used to get better line breaking that is more or less expected. You could add `\sloppy` to the start of your document, but the combination of sloppy and no hyphenation is not going to be pretty.

Comment: I you don't want to either enable hyphenation or use the `\sloppy` directive, you will probably need to rewrite the parts of the paragraphs that are currently generating overfull lines.